# How to pass parameters to command with Laravel Task Scheduling

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-scheduler

As the official docs, it doesn't mention about this a lot.
`App\Console\Commands\PullUsersCommand.php` has a signature like:

```
protected $signature = 'pull:users {startTime} {endTime} {minutes=10} {--flag} {--star=}';
```

So, how to pass the parameters to it in `App\Console\Kernel.php`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could call it in App\Console\Kernel.php like this:

```
$schedule->command('pull:users', [
    time(),  // captured with $this->argument('startTime') in command class.
    time(),  // captured with $this->argument('endTime') in command class.
    30,      // captured with $this->argument('minutes') in command class.
    '--flag',// should be without any value, just the option name, and would be captured by $this->option('minutes').
    '--star'=>12, // would be captured by $this->option('star').
])->daily();
```

It should be okay with `Artisan::call` facade too.